# Kovan Test Net: not receiving test LINK

Tags: kovan, erc-677

I tried to receive Link on the Kovan testnet two different ways, with the same result- No error message, it just continues to load endlessly.

1. https://kovan.chain.link/. a) "Send me 100 test link", b) your transaction was successful c) check metamask for link (none) d) import tokens- add token contact address
   (0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088) e) add token symbol and decimal (link/18) f) add custom token (but there is not balance!) g) click import tokens and continuous loading.
2. https://faucets.chain.link/ connected to  my metamask test addresss.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue even though I switched browsers , the solution is that you use this address:
LINK Token `0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709`

From the chainlink docs, see here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#rinkeby-testnet

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, keep in mind that Kovan is now deprecated along with Rinkeby and Kovan. Goerli is now the primary Ethereum testnet.

Here's a reputable Goerli testETH faucet (there's scams out there) - https://goerlifaucet.com